# Use batch file to parse Jmeter xml response file and print output on console

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, jmeter, batch-processing

I have a Jmeter response file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample t="22" lt="11" ts="1500633511099" s="true" lb="Url check" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="543" ng="1" na="1">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <httpSample t="11" lt="11" ts="1500633511099" s="true" lb="http://ipaddress/application" rc="302" rm="Found" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="" by="149" ng="1" na="1"/>
  <httpSample t="10" lt="10" ts="1500633511111" s="true" lb="http://ipaddress/application/" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="394" ng="1" na="1"/>
</httpSample>
<httpSample t="196" lt="196" ts="1500633511133" s="true" lb="Login" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="1204" ng="1" na="1">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion - HttpOnly</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
</httpSample>
<httpSample t="98" lt="98" ts="1500633511350" s="true" lb="Logout" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="986" ng="1" na="1">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
</httpSample>

</testResults>
```

I want to parse this file using **batch file** and get the output of  the following attributes ie only value:

1. httpSample -> lb
2. httpSample -> rc
3. httpSample -> rm

Ive created a batch file as follows but it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
set tag=httpSample
set f_xml=response.xml
(for /F "tokens=5,6,7 delims=<=>" %%a in ('findstr "\</%tag%\>" %f_xml%') do echo  (
    IF /i "%%a"=="lb" SET "printme=Y"   %%~a %%b
    IF /i "%%a"=="rc" SET "printme=Y"   %%~a %%b
    IF /i "%%a"=="rm" SET "printme=Y"   %%~a %%b
 )
 )
```

Also I want to print my own text as key for the output. 
Infact, this response.xml is not having complete the actual responses that we get for each call in **Jmeter GUI** . It just states success or failure. How can i get all the response data in **Jmeter non-gui mode i.e command line mode**?

For eg. If the output from %%a is  `http://ipaddress/application`  then i want to print  `ipadderss=http://ipaddress/application`

Comment: you can check [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)  -> E.g. for getting `rc`  values `call xpath.bat http.xml "//httpSample/@rc"`

Comment: `powershell "([xml](gc response.xml)).SelectNodes('//httpSample[contains(@lb,\"://\")]') | %{ \"lb={0}\`nrc={1}\`nrm={2}\" -f $_.lb, $_.rc, $_.rm }"` from the cmd console, or double the percent sign if calling from a .bat script.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is an example which only picks out the specific data you requested from the specific content provided.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "tag=httpSample"
Set "f_xml=response.xml"
For /F "Delims=>" %%A In ('FindStr "\<%tag%\>" "%f_xml%"'
) Do For /F Tokens^=10^,12^,14Delims^=^" %%B In ("%%A"
) Do Echo "%%B" "%%C" "%%D"
Pause
```

It could be expanded but using a batch file for reading xml data and not utilising other languages is definitely not recommended or usually worth the effort.

Comment: Batch file is used to run Jmeter in non-gui mode...so first jmeter suite is run using command line, response xml is created and then i wanted to display the response there itself on the console. What would be better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want response data to be saved you need to explicitly "tell" JMeter to do it, you have the following options:

1. Ad-hoc (once only) setting pass the relevant property via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options):

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Permanent setting. If you want JMeter to always store response data you need to add the aforementioned line to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

Remember that using XML format for storing JMeter test results and especially saving response data are not [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as they create large disk IO overhead and may have negative impact on your load test results.